# Navigation Drawer Activity open window

Tags: android

I have a list, I want that when I click on the first line my application goes to another window and I do not know how to do it, I'm new, please explain[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ytMa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainActivity.java you should have an overriden function that looks like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.option1) {

    } else if (id == R.id.option2) {

    } else if (id == R.id.option3) {

    } else if (id == R.id.option4) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

and if you want to launch another activity when you click the option1 button then you should add an intent for the activity you want to open inside the option1 'if' brackets:

```
Intent loginintent = new Intent(this, activity_youractivity.class);
startActivity(loginintent);
```

activity_youractivity here is name of the java file in which you want to go further.
Ex- Home.class (Home is the activity's java file name and .class is used to call that activity's class which is fixed to use)
You can also change IDs in menu.xml and must repeat that change in this function.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks bro, i did it